# Regex: Split X length words

Tags: asp.net, regex, vb.net

I'm new to regular expresions. I have a gigantic text. In the aplication, i need words of 4 characters and delete the rest. The text is in spanish. So far, I can select 4 char length words but i still need to delete the rest.

This is my regular expression

```
\s(\w{3,3}[a-zA-ZáéíóúäëïöüñÑ])\s
```

How can i get all words with 4 letters in asp.net vb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the character class provided above in another answer (\w does NOT match spanish word characters unfortunately).

You can use this for a match (it matches the reverse, basically matches everything that is *NOT* a 4-character word, so you can replace with " ", leaving only the 4-character words):

```
/(^|(?<=(?<=\W)[a-zA-ZáéíóúäëïöüñÑ]{4,4}(?=\W)))(.*?)((?=(?<=\W)[a-zA-ZáéíóúäëïöüñÑ]{4,4}(?=\W))|$)/gis
```

Approximated code in VB (not tested):

```
  Dim input As String = "This is your text"
  Dim pattern As String = "/(^|(?<=(?<=\W)[a-zA-ZáéíóúäëïöüñÑ]{4,4}(?=\W)))(.*?)((?=(?<=\W)[a-zA-ZáéíóúäëïöüñÑ]{4,4}(?=\W))|$)/gis"
  Dim replacement As String = " "
  Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)
  Dim result As String = rgx.Replace(input, replacement)

  Console.WriteLine("Original String: {0}", input)
  Console.WriteLine("Replacement String: {0}", result)
```

You can see the result of the regex in action here:

http://regexr.com?30n29

Answer (score 3):

`/(?:\A|(?<=\P{L}))(\p{L}{4})(?:(?=\P{L})|\z)/g`

**Explanation:**

Switch `/g` is for repeatedly search

`\A` is start of the string (not start of line)

`\p{L}` matches a single code point in the category *letter*

`\P{L}` matches a single code point not in the category *letter*

`{n}` specify a specific amount of repetition [*n* is number]

`\z` is end of string (not end of line)

`|` is logic *OR* operator

`(?<=)` is lookbehind

`(?=)` is lookahead

`(?:)` is non backreference grouping

`()` is backreference grouping

Comment: (1) VB doesn't support regex literals;  (2) it has no equivalent for the `/g` flag--you just call (for example) `Matches()` instead of `Match()`; (3) `\p{L}` matches uppercase and lowercase letters already, so you don't need the `/i` flag (or equivalent).

Comment: @chepe263 - gskinner.com does not support `\p{L}` and `\P{L}`

Answer (score -2):

```
\[^a-zA-ZáéíóúäëïöüñÑ][a-zA-ZáéíóúäëïöüñÑ]{4}[^a-zA-ZáéíóúäëïöüñÑ]\g
```

Translated:
A non-letter, followed by 4 letters, followed by a non-letter.  The 'g' indicated will match globally ... more than once.

Check out this link to find out more info on looping over your matches:
http://osherove.com/blog/2003/5/12/practical-parsing-using-groups-in-regular-expressions.html

Comment: **Will not work** if 4-letter word will be very first or very last in string, with no non-letter before/after the word